# JSON Api how to represent to-many relationship in objects in primary data

Tags: json-api

In JSON API I need to represent a collection of primary data where the primary data objects have to-many relationship to themselves.

ie.

```
account1 -> canTransferTo (relationship) -account3
account2 -> canTransferTo (relationship) -account1, account3
account3 -> canTransferTo (relationship) -account1
```

how will I do that so that I follow the JSO API specifications. Can it be like this below?

```
{
"data": [{
    "type": "accounts",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "account1"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "canTransferTo": {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/accounts/1/relationships/canTransferTo",
                "related": "http://example.com/accounts/1/canTransferTo"
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "accounts",
                "id": "3"
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/accounts/1"
    }
}, {
    "type": "accounts",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "account2"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "canTransferTo": {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/accounts/2/relationships/canTransferTo",
                "related": "http://example.com/accounts/2/canTransferTo"
            },
            "data": [{
                "type": "accounts",
                "id": "1"
            }, {
                "type": "accounts",
                "id": "3"
            }]
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/accounts/2"
    }
}, {
    "type": "accounts",
    "id": "3",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "account3"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "canTransferTo": {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/accounts/3/relationships/canTransferTo",
                "related": "http://example.com/accounts/3/canTransferTo"
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "accounts",
                "id": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/accounts/3"
    }
}]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, the JSON you pasted is not a valid JSON. You can validate any JSON at [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). 
I guess you pasted your JSON skipping the enclosing **"}"** character. If I put it to the end of your JSON, it seems to be correct, according to the page mentioned above.

If you want to validate your JSON against JSON-API specification, you can find the specification schema on http://jsonapi.org/schema and paste it on this page: http://jsonschemalint.com/ together with the JSON you want to validate.

After fixing it adding "}" to the end, the jsonschemalint told me it is a JSON-API-compliant object ;-)

Comment: Glad to help! p.s.: accept my answer if it helped solve your problem ;)